# Message appears when running scsslint

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I am following the step by step on https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-scss-lint
I have installed everything, and seems to be working fine when I type in Terminal 'scss-lint'.

However I want this to be running in Grunt

Gruntfile:

```
    scsslint: {
        allFiles: [
            'src/scss/**/*.scss',
        ],
        options: {
            bundleExec: true,
            config: '.scss-lint.yml',
            reporterOutput: 'scss-lint-report.xml',
            colorizeOutput: true
        }
    },

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['js', 'html', 'scsslint',]);
```

so I type in grunt in terminal which will run the tasks and in terminal - this pops up:

> > Running "scsslint:allFiles" (scsslint) task
> >
> > Running scss-lint on allFiles
> >
> > 1. Please make sure you have ruby installed: `ruby -v`
> > 2. Install the `scss-lint` gem by running:
> >        gem update --system && gem install scss-lint

Running through grunt does not work but typing scss-lint in terminal works.
I did the following message but this message does not disappear

Comment: Yes ruby has been installed otherwise how would scsslint works if i type in scss-lint in terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to the `bundleExec` parameter. If you set it to `true`, the plugin will expect the gem to be installed via bundler.

Set it to `false`, and it will work.

```
scsslint: {
    allFiles: [
        'src/scss/**/*.scss',
    ],
    options: {
        bundleExec: false,
        config: '.scss-lint.yml',
        reporterOutput: 'scss-lint-report.xml',
        colorizeOutput: true
    }
},

grunt.registerTask('default', ['js', 'html', 'scsslint',]);
```

Comment: Cheers, I just have to remove it. Thanks!